# Assigning different variables with similar name in a loop

Tags: c#, variables, loops

I have 10 textboxes, named textBox1, textBox2 to textBox10. I would like to assign string text in each:

```
textBox1.text = "Stackoverflow1";
textBox2.text = "Stackoverflow2";
...
textBox10.text = "Stackoverflow10";
```

Is is possible to make it happen in a loop? Something like:

```
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
    ???? = "Stackoverflow" + i.ToString();
}
```

I was thinking to use a list, but could I possibly adding the "variable" to a list? Say if I create a list:

```
List<String> Testing = new List<String>();
Testing.add(textBox1.text);
Testing.add(textBox2.text);
...
Testing.add(textBox10.text);
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
    Testing[i-1] = "Stackoverflow" + i.ToString();
}
```

But this could not work because Testing[] is a string, not a variable in this case. How would I achieve the purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You almost had it. Just put the text boxes themselves in the list, not the strings.

```
List<TextBox> textBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
textBoxes.Add(textBox1);
textBoxes.Add(textBox2);
textBoxes.Add(textBox3);
// etc.

for (int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Count; ++i)
{
    textBoxes[i].Text = "Stackoverflow" + (i + 1).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Now it is faster to assigning different variable together using the List method.